# memory error while submitting Rscript job through slurm

Tags: r, linux, datatable, out-of-memory, slurm

I have a R script which i am submitting through slurm.
This R script it loop through 2150 genes across 31 tissues and create a output table which stores whether for a particular gene I am getting gene model for it across all the tissues.
I submitted this job through slurm but it run for 1 day and then throw an error.

This the error I am getting:

```
Error in write.table(models_df, file = paste0(genes_union[k], ".txt"),  :
  Error writing to connection:  No space left on device
Execution halted
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this error.
I also have cut the main job into many small job to loop through less genes.
Thank you.

Comment: The error indicates that you filled up the hard drive you were writing to. You should talk to your cluster administrator to see if there is somewhere else you should be writing files to. There’s not much you can do about this with code.

Comment: You should also check how much output you expect per gene-tissue combination and whether it makes sense that you filled up the disk. Your code may not be doing what you think.